# How can I Simulate External Drives on Android Studio?

Tags: external-sd, usb-on-the-go

I'm currently working on a small internal application for my company. (non-commercial, just a QoL app) The plan is to connect several hard drives to one mobile device and simultaneously flash them all for backup purposes, rather than connect the drives one at a time, the plan is to connect them all at once via an on-the-go cable.

For testing purposes, I was wondering if there was a way to emulate external hard-drives on Android Studio?

(also any advice is welcome!)

Edit: I'm looking for a way to simulate any external drive within studio

Comment: I am not aware of an OTG simulation for the Android emulator. For such hardware related apps you should test on real devices.

Comment: Additionally no requirement exists in the [Android Compatibility Definition Document](https://source.android.com/docs/compatibility/cdd) for OTG support. So I'm not even sure how one would test this in emulator. Agree with Robert, you'll need to use a physical device for testing.

Comment: Cross-posted from SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73672214/2821954